# Not sure how to formulate this query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am using VBA to run a query in access.

This is the query I insert into a variable:

```
SQL = "SELECT * INTO " & _
strNEW & _
" FROM tblTotaalVerlies WHERE 'Filename' LIKE *\" & _
strNEW & _
"\*;"
```

Which, when using `Debug.Print(SQL)` gives me the following query:

```
SELECT * INTO 1300 FROM tblTotaalVerlies WHERE 'Filename' LIKE *\1300\*
```

I have tried several variations on this query like:

```
SELECT * INTO 1300 FROM tblTotaalVerlies WHERE 'Filename' LIKE *\1300\*;
SELECT * INTO 1300 FROM tblTotaalVerlies WHERE 'Filename' LIKE *\1300\*
SELECT * INTO 1300 FROM tblTotaalVerlies WHERE Filename LIKE %\1300\*%;
```

and none work. What is the correct way to get this query running?

Comment: do you have table with name 1300 ?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: @Kamal The error that I get is `Error 3075` `Syntax error: missing operator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL = "SELECT * INTO " & _
strNEW & _
" FROM tblTotaalVerlies WHERE [Filename] LIKE '%" & _
strNEW & _
"%';"
```

Comment: Well the string I am looking for is dependent on the Var "strNEW"

Comment: see answer from @CheemunLow below, I missed the part about you having the column name in single quotes which means its checking the string 'FileName' rather than the contents of the column.

But add single quote and percent sign around the your Like string'
    
    SQL = "SELECT * INTO " & _
    strNEW & _
    " FROM tblTotaalVerlies WHERE [Filename] LIKE '%" & _
    strNEW & _
    "%';"

Answer (score 1):

filename is sql reserved word

cover your filename with bracket like [FileName] like below

```
SQL = "SELECT * INTO " & _
strNEW & _
" FROM tblTotaalVerlies WHERE [Filename] LIKE *\" & _
strNEW & _
"\*;"
```

Comment: apparently, the wildcard to use in the "Like" is a "%" in access

Comment: oops,forgot to check your query = = but seem like someone is already correct it for u